# Grab my linkedin profile URL programatically

Tags: puppeteer, linkedin-api

I understand the necessity of establishing a partnership with LinkedIn to access their "Profile API." However, I have an unrelated inquiry.

I'm considering creating a mobile app that enables users to **access the URL** of their **own** LinkedIn profile (https://www.linkedin.com/in/vanityName). Let's assume the user is already logged into their LinkedIn app on their phone.

Could you recommend some methods to accomplish this? Could Puppeteer be a viable option?

Comment: What does "logged in" mean? Is it on some browser or app?

Comment: @rkochar The user is already signed in on the LinkedIn app on phone.

Comment: You surely understand why it would be a bad idea if your app could just access data of any other app installed on your device?

Comment: Using Puppeteer or any form of automated script to interact with LinkedIn, in a manner that mimics human behavior or accesses user data without explicit permission is against the terms of service of LinkedIn.

Comment: @derpirscher That's not an answer to my question

Comment: @GagBaghdasaryan with this logic, MS Excel that allows running macros and RPA softwares (like uiPath) should be banned. Think..

Comment: Because there is no answer to your question. Your app cannot access the data of the LinkedIn app to read the logged in user or credentials. End of story. You can of course always just access that url with a simple http request. But you will have to provide your own login mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible for one app (the one you write) to access data from another app (LinkedIn), unless the other app specifically exposes it. And LinkedIn does not expose the name of currently logged-in user.

So what you are asking is not possible, by design.

(Unless user's phone is rooted/jailbroken and you use special permissions to bypass system protection. But I am guessing you want this to apply to all phones. Plus, even on rooted phones you need to explicitly grant special permissions to app, and people don't grant those without a very good reason.)

Comment: What about querying https://www.linkedin.com/in using HTTP GET ? I've noticed that when I go to this url using my chrome browser, it automatically refers me to my actual linkedin profile url (it automatically fills in the vanty name). Is there any way to grab it from the HTTP response?

Comment: When you use Chrome browser to go to URLs, Chrome sends its cookies along the request, and those cookies point to your username. And the cookies are stored in app-specific storage and are not shared with any other apps. 

You can verify this yourself very easily: install a different non-Google browser (Firefox? Edge?) and try to go to linkedin. You will get a login page instead of your own. That's because only Google products have access to Chrome's cookie storage.